# How did Dryden Vos collect the relics in his office?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

In Solo, we see Dryden Vos has a number of different artifacts, most notably a set of Mandalorian armour and a Sith holocron. **How did he collect these items since they are incredibly hard to get hold of?***

*- I assume that from watching the Clone Wars and Rebels that no Mandalorian would easily give their armour away, without a fight at least.

Comment: The Sith hardly give up their holocrons easily either.

Comment: Did you miss the part where he's fabulously wealthy and has a tendency to pay people to steal him things?

Comment: @Valorum Fair point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's some additional details in the film's [Official Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story_The_Official_Guide). In short, Dryden uses a mixture of legal and non-legal methods to acquire the items in his collection.

> **OBJECTS OF INTEREST**
>
> The displays in Dryden's study are only a fraction of the rarities in
>   his collection. Vos rotates out the galleries at whim, requesting
>   items from storehouses on Tanaab, Byblos, Cato Neimoidia, and
>   elsewhere. **He employs well-paid buyers and relic-hunters to risk their
>   lives in order to find him new trophies.**

and

> **PERSONAL MUSEUM**
>
> **Dryden Vos does not follow any of the regulations that prevent ethical
>   archaeologists from taking items sacred to other cultures.** His display
>   of mystical antiquities includes Rafa life crystals, arks that hold
>   the ashes of Chancellor Contispex I, Rakatan wraith boxes, and the
>   Dancing Goddess idol of the Godoan people.

As to the presence of a reconditioned Sith Holocron, there's another Sith item in his collection, raided from a Sith Temple. It's possible (and in fact, downright likely) that they came from the same source.

[image]